# Linux gmod сервер не перезапускается

Tags: linux, сервер

Установил игровой сервер Garry`d Mod с помощью https://linuxgsm.com/, на Linux под Ubuntu.
Всё работает штатно, но как только сервер внутри игры крашится, то процесс не перезапускается. Сервер не появляется в списке, но статус у него онлайн.

Есть ли возможность сделать проверку того, отвечает ли процесс, и если нет, то повторно его запустить?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по документации, [вполне себе есть](https://docs.linuxgsm.com/commands/monitor).

> monitor checks the game server to ensure the server functioning. First checking the game server process is running then querying the game server to check the game server is responding. monitor is designed to be an automated command that frequently checks the game server, rebooting and alerting if required.